# Access container running mongodb using private IP

Tags: containers, ibm-cloud

In Bluemix I have a container running an instance of MongoDb. I would like to connect to the MongoDb from a Node.js CF application. Do I really have to assign a public IP address to the container to do this? Can I use the Bluemix VPN service to create a tunnel to the container?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to reach an IBM Container from a Bluemix application using the private container IP, since the environments are in different networks. The Bluemix VPN service is used to provide secure connectivity between your Bluemix resources and your on-premises data center. It allows to securely access IBM containers via private IP, but you need an IPSec VPN gateway at your data center or SoftLayer server to form a secure connection with that service.

Comment: So there is no way that I can connect to eg. a Mongo db in a container from a CF app? Not without assigning a public IP?

Comment: You will not be able to reach an IBM Container from a Bluemix application using the private container IP, the environments are in different networks. The infrastructure is shared and an application can be restaged in a totally different network for example when you push a new version. The only safe way is to use the public IP route.